CORS Error when using Socket.io with Ngrok
I'm building a Node app that uses http and socket, and i'm exposing my localhost using Ngrok and letting other user connect to my react app using my IP4 Address.
i always get this error :
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘https://a29a-41-109-30-183.ngrok-free.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O-hTmol’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).
I setup the CORS like this :
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173", "http://192.168.1.6:5173"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new SocketIOServer(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173", "http://192.168.1.6:5173"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

and on the client side :
const socket = io(backend_url_socket, {
    withCredentials: true,
    extraHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${secureLocalStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
      "Another-Header": "HeaderValue",
    },
  });
  socket.on("connect", () => {});


Based on your error response its using https but it seems that your server is listening for http connections. You can try starting the ngrok service to use http instead of https
In your terminal run


ngrok --scheme http http 3000



In the example I use port 3000 but change it to whatever your localhost is listening on.
